# How to deploy angular app using webpack5 module federation on IIS?

Tags: angular, iis, webpack, deployment, webpack-5

I'm trying to deploy on IIS an [app](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-plugin-architecture-with-module-federation) that uses webpack5 module federation built with ngx-build-plus custom builder with [extraWebpackConfig file](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-plugin-architecture-with-module-federation/blob/main/src/webpack.config.js) defined in [angular.json](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-plugin-architecture-with-module-federation/blob/main/angular.json). The app starts to load normally and favicon is got but then it results in error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Loading chunk 203 failed.
(error: http://localhost:4200/203.f429868b020a9d24d2de.js) ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 203 failed.
(error: http://localhost:4200/203.f429868b020a9d24d2de.js)
    at Object.j.f.j (http://localhost/webpack5-test/main.cbf4c029cfb79ab77242.js:1:6321)
    at http://localhost/webpack5-test/main.cbf4c029cfb79ab77242.js:1:485
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Function.j.e (http://localhost/webpack5-test/main.cbf4c029cfb79ab77242.js:1:451)
    at http://localhost/webpack5-test/main.cbf4c029cfb79ab77242.js:1:6874
    at http://localhost/webpack5-test/main.cbf4c029cfb79ab77242.js:1:6930 ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 203 failed.
(error: http://localhost:4200/203.f429868b020a9d24d2de.js)
    at Object.j.f.j (http://localhost/webpack5-test/main.cbf4c029cfb79ab77242.js:1:6321)
    at http://localhost/webpack5-test/main.cbf4c029cfb79ab77242.js:1:485
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Function.j.e (http://localhost/webpack5-test/main.cbf4c029cfb79ab77242.js:1:451)
    at http://localhost/webpack5-test/main.cbf4c029cfb79ab77242.js:1:6874
    at http://localhost/webpack5-test/main.cbf4c029cfb79ab77242.js:1:6930
```

How to deploy the app on IIS successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is wrong module.exports publicPath in extraWebpackConfig file (webpack.config.js).

Just in case someone else is trying something similar below are the complete steps to deploy [both apps](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-plugin-architecture-with-module-federation) on IIS. plugins app exposes and provides the plugins for "main app" so they both need to be running.

1. edit src/webpack.config.js to have correct publicPath

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost/webpack5-test/',
    uniqueName: 'app'
  },
```

2. edit projects/plugins/webpack.config.js to have correct publicPath

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost/plugins-test/',
    uniqueName: 'plugins'
  },
```

3. edit src/assets/plugins.config.json to load the plugins (modules) from plugins-test:

```
{
  "plugin1": {
    "mfEntry": "http://localhost/plugins-test/remoteEntry.js",
    "name": "plugins",
    "exposedModule": "./Plugin1",
    "ngModuleName": "Plugin1Component"
  },
  "plugin2": {
    "mfEntry": "http://localhost/plugins-test/remoteEntry.js",
    "name": "plugins",
    "exposedModule": "./Plugin2",
    "ngModuleName": "Plugin2Component"
  }
}
```

4. run

```
ng build plugins --prod --base-href /plugins-test/
```

copy files from dist/plugins to wwwroot/plugins-test/ and convert folder to application in IIS.

5. run

```
ng build --prod --base-href /webpack5-test/
```

copy files from dist/angular-plugin-architecture-module-federation to wwwroot/webpack5-test/ and convert folder to application in IIS.

Comment: What's wrong was with publicPath? Can't find how it looked before

Comment: @Roman: it was in the linked example app. see the link. Anyway paths had port numbers in urls.